# Correlated random slopes and intercepts but non-significant random slopes. Can you have one without the other?

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I am running a multilevel model. When I compare the random slope without a correlation (Model 2) model to the just random intercept model (Model 1) it is not significant (via likelihood-ratio test). But the random slope with correlation between slope and intercept model (Model 3) does come out significantly better than the random slope only model (Model 2). If the slopes don't really vary, how can they be correlated with the intercept? Is it a prerequisite to first have a significant random slopes model to then see if the slopes are correlated with the intercepts?

```
Model_1 <- lmer(  M_english_1 ~ B_english_0 + classuse + EMIS_TotalEnrolment + (1 | School_ID), data = TZ_Data)

Model_2 <- lmer(  M_english_1 ~ B_english_0 + classuse + EMIS_TotalEnrolment + (1 | School_ID) + (0 + classuse | School_ID), data = TZ_Data)

Model_3 <- lmer(  M_english_1 ~ B_english_0 + classuse + EMIS_TotalEnrolment + (1 + classuse | School_ID), data = TZ_Data)
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I just edited the question above with the R Syntax I am using.

Comment: I appreciate it!